# Pass NameSpace to object and save to localstorage

Tags: javascript, angular, inappbrowser, sap-smp

Hello I have an android application that opens up the device certificates and get some information back from it (APPCID).

```
  handleCeritifcate(appid) {
OData.defaultHttpClient = sap.AuthProxy.generateODataHttpClient();
this.factory.connectionData = { DeviceType: "Android" };
this.factory.clientCert = new sap.AuthProxy.CertificateFromStore();

console.log("app clientcert:", this.factory.clientCert);


var sUrl = this.factory.baseUrl + "/odata/applications/latest/" + appid + "/Connections";

var request = {
  headers: {},
  certificateSource: this.factory.clientCert,
  requestUri: sUrl,
  data: this.factory.connectionData,
  method: "POST"
};


OData.request(request, (result => {
  // this.onSuccessForRegister(result);
  console.log("certificate success:", result);

}), (error) => {
  console.log("ceritficate error", error);
});
```

}

[image]

I want to save the value I get from `this.factory.clientCert` and save to `localstorage` so I can pass it to another app , I'm using inappbrowser postmessage to pass data between sites.
But when I try to save `clientCert`, it only saves the JSON inside it:

```
{ SYSTEM : SOURCE }
```

without the `AuthProxy.CertificateFromStore`.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store an instated object into the localstorage.

You can try to convert the instance with `JSON.stringify()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)) and then save that.

```
localStorage.setItem(clientCert, JSON.stringify(this.factory.clientCert));

console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("clientCert"));
```

Comment: Hello Tom , I've tried what you suggested but I'm still not saving the instance as I intented.
I'm getting an object just with
{ Source : "SYSTEM" } instead of with AuthProxy.CertificateFromStore